# How to slow/prevent corrosion of a steel post

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry, ph

I have a steel post set in limestone, about 18-20 inches deep, with some concrete around it.

I just noticed that I have about 6 inches of water inside the post. The limestone had a small seam in it and I believe the water seeps through it.
I am concerned about long term corrosion.

I am about to cap the post, so I will have no access to it in the future.
What can I do to prevent/slow the corrosion?

A. Nothing. Do not worry about it.
 B. Fill the post with crushed limestone 12 inches above grade.
 C. Fill the post with concrete 12 inches above grade.
 D. Install a fitting in the post and dump some concentrated washing soda solution or powder once or twice per year to raise pH.
 E. Some type of cathodic protection.
 F. Other.

I am leaning toward B. This would be easy to accomplish and inexpensive, and limestone is supposed to raise pH level, which I think should slow corrosion.

Comment: I'm no expert on the chemistry stack exchange, but I think you may get a more practical answer on [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Perhaps. I am afraid most people do not give this much thought, so the scientific approach might yield better results.

Comment: Do you know what kind of steel it is (carbon steel, stainless steel, galvanized)?

Comment: Just regular carbon steel.

Comment: Carbon steel can handle *slightly* basic conditions, so concentrated soda wouldn't be a go to solution. If the post isn't critical for safely supporting something or a related critical function, I think you can go with the limestone idea. If you could borrow/rent a pump and get rid of the water, that would be ideal. If you poured some concrete, could you use the ready to mix stuff that would react with the water in the post?

Comment: Unfortunately, the water infiltration will be an ongoing process, so I would have to have a permanent pump that would come on automatically as needed. Doable, but way too much hassle. After thinking some more, concrete is not a good idea, as any condensate above could pool on top of the concrete and freeze in the winter, cracking the post. This is a structural post, so it is somewhat critical, but probably not life or death critical.

Comment: Your idea of cathodic protection might work. Perhaps you could melt some zinc and pour it into the (dried out) post, effectively galvanizing at least part of it. It might not adhere well, but should provide some protection.

Comment: Could you put a cap on the end that is open to the atmosphere after emptying it? If the water has room to expand in the vertical direction, I don't think freezing will crack the pipe.